# How to build a Lego MindStorm EV3 binary?

Tags: c, arm, u-boot, nxt, bare-metal

We are trying to write a pseudo-OS for an [ev3 Lego brick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lego_Mindstorms_EV3). We already know, that there is an u-boot loader in the ROM of the brick, and that it loads an *uImage* file from the first partition of the SD-Card. We have tried to understand how the [Linux ev3 kernel](https://github.com/mindboards/ev3dev-kernel) works and where is the entry point (assuming the **main** function). We have a potential [entry point](https://github.com/mindboards/ev3dev-kernel/blob/master/arch/arm/kernel/head.S#L67), but we don't know, how this location is marked as entry points or how to code a simplified version.

We want to create our own binary, which can be converted to an *uImage* file (with [mkimage](http://linux.die.net/man/1/mkimage)).

- How do we have to do this?
- How to mark a certain C-function as entry point?

Comment: hm... the problem is, that we want to create or own `<input.bin>` and dont know how to do this.

Comment: The way your question is worded is wrong then.  Really, it has nothing with u-boot.  You want to google, [*bare metal arm*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arm+bare-metal); the topic is huge.  You need to know about linker files, 'c' startup and CPU initialization.  The Linux *head.S* is the start point for Linux, but it is too complex for what you want.  Look in the [u-boot examples](http://git.denx.de/?p=u-boot.git;a=tree;f=examples/standalone;hb=HEAD).

Comment: Sorry for the wrong wording, but im a newby in this topic. I tried to formulate it in the best way a can... ^^ Yes, head.S is to complex, so im looking now for a minimized version. I will take a look at the link you posted.